# Radiating Spokes Off Of A Circle

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I have ran into a little bit of a maths issue, I feel like this should be easy to solve but I am missing a tiny bit of information haha.

If you look at the fiddle I have set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/e9ds5/. You can see how all of the "nodes" are aligned. What I am trying to do is get the node titled "one" in the centre with all of the others around the outside of it.

So the current angle all of the nodes have to go off to is 90 degrees (4 items around the outside). Therefore I thought I should be able to do a

```
var getAngle = function(ang) {
    return {x: Math.cos(ang), y: Math.sin(ang)};
}
```

and then when I want to go off in that angle

```
  var centerX = function (d, i) {
    return (getAngle(ang_inc).x * i) * 100 + base.x;
  };

  var centerY = function (a, i) {
    return (getAngle(ang_inc).y * i) * 100 + base.y;
  }
```

Thanks everyone, try not to be to harsh on my sub average math ability haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.sin and Math.cos expect the angle in radians, use 2*Math.PI for the full circle.

Or use the conversion in

```
  var getAngle = function(ang) {
    ang_in_rad = (ang*Math.PI)/180;
    return {x: Math.cos(ang_in_rad), y: Math.sin(ang_in_rad)};
  }
```

In the center function, you want the multiple of the angle, not the radius. So multiply angle_inc with i. However, strange things happen when the radius is not multiplied by pi. So treat the special case i==0 in a special way to get radius zero.

```
  var centerX = function (d, i) {
    return getAngle(ang_inc*i).x * ((i==0)?0:100) + base.x;
  };

  var centerY = function (a, i) {
    return getAngle(ang_inc*i).y * ((i==0)?0:100) + base.y;
  };
```

Now you have to adjust the text positioning,...

Answer (score 1):

If you want D3 to do all the maths, you could use D3's force layout. Of course you'd have to create a small data structure for the graph. Here's how it's done:

```
var graph = {
  nodes: [
    {"name": "1", "group": 1},
    {"name": "2", "group": 1}, 
    {"name": "3", "group": 1}, 
    {"name": "4", "group": 1}, 
    {"name": "5", "group": 1}
  ],
  links: [
    {"source": 0, "target": 0, "value": 1},
    {"source": 0, "target": 1, "value": 1}, 
    {"source": 0, "target": 2, "value": 1},
    {"source": 0, "target": 3, "value": 1},
    {"source": 0, "target": 4, "value": 1}
  ]
};

var width = 500,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(50)
    .charge(-1500)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g");

node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
    .attr("dx", -5).attr("dy", 5);


force.on("tick", function () {
    link
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E76wD/23/) that shows you how it works.

Comment: Do you think this would strictly be the best way to  solve the issue?

Comment: @Hcwool IMHO, since you're using D3 I think this would be the best way; make use of what it gives you :). You could easily add more nodes later if you wanted to and not have to worry about the circles overlapping since the force layout takes care of that for you.